# Setting up hard drive in QEMU+KVM?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am using QEMU+KVM+OVMF for a Windows VM. 
Is there a way to mount physical hard drives to the VM only without using a container, as well as keep the data that is still on them?

There are examples of this I assume but I only see them in XML format and I use QEMU command line script. Not very familiar with conversions, no idea what format I'd need to put it in.

http://pastebin.com/WRaZuM02
The script I use. I supposedly need to use UUID for my hard drives but I never seen that used in CLI before.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the hard disk as the "file" qemu should use, for example `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/disk/by-uuid/some-uuid-here`.  Of course, you must make sure nothing else is using that disk other than this vm or bad things (TM) will happen.

Comment: Would this be right then? -drive file=/dev/sdc2,id=disk2,if=none -device scsi-hd,drive=disk2 \

Comment: @KylerParson, /dev/sdc2 is an individual partition of a disk, not a whole disk, which is what you asked about.  I recommend using either regular files or LVM logical volumes to hold disk images.  The nice thing about these is that you can give the vm a much larger virtual disk that only uses a fraction of that size to store the data it has actually written to the disk, and it can grow over time, rather than reserving a fixed amount when you create it, and having to deal with the hassle of resizing and moving partitions.